# blpapi.exception.UnsupportedOperationException: No subscription management endpoints for snapshot (0x00080013)

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to request snapshot from Bloomberg through Python API using the example programs that Bloomberg provided with the package. Their own program doesn't work properly and I keep getting the error:

`WARN blpapi_subscriptionmanager.cpp:1653 blpapi.session.subscriptionmanager.{1} Subscription management endpoints are required for snapshot request templates but none are available`

`blpapi.exception.UnsupportedOperationException: No subscription management endpoints for snapshot (0x00080013).`

The part of the code that has the snapshot request is in main func:

```
def main():
    """main entry point"""
    global options
    options = parseCmdLine()

# Create a session and Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    for idx, host in enumerate(options.hosts):
        sessionOptions.setServerAddress(host, options.port, idx)
    sessionOptions.setAuthenticationOptions(options.auth)
    sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(True)

    print("Connecting to port %d on %s" % (
        options.port, ", ".join(options.hosts)))

    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

    if not session.start():
        print("Failed to start session.")
        return

    subscriptionIdentity = None
    if options.auth:
        subscriptionIdentity = session.createIdentity()
        isAuthorized = False
        authServiceName = "//blp/apiauth"
        if session.openService(authServiceName):
            authService = session.getService(authServiceName)
            isAuthorized = authorize(authService, subscriptionIdentity,
                                     session, blpapi.CorrelationId("auth"))
        if not isAuthorized:
            print("No authorization")
            return
    else:
        print("Not using authorization")

# Snapshot Request Part:

    fieldStr = "?fields=" + ",".join(options.fields)

    snapshots = []
    nextCorrelationId = 0
    for i, topic in enumerate(options.topics):
        subscriptionString = options.service + topic + fieldStr
        snapshots.append(session.createSnapshotRequestTemplate(
            subscriptionString,
            subscriptionIdentity,
            blpapi.CorrelationId(i)))
        nextCorrelationId += 1

    requestTemplateAvailable = blpapi.Name('RequestTemplateAvailable')
    eventCount = 0
    try:
        while True:
            # Specify timeout to give a chance for Ctrl-C
            event = session.nextEvent(1000)
            for msg in event:
                if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.ADMIN and  \
                        msg.messageType() == requestTemplateAvailable:

                    for requestTemplate in snapshots:
                        session.sendRequestTemplate(
                            requestTemplate,
                            blpapi.CorrelationId(nextCorrelationId))
                        nextCorrelationId += 1

                elif event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or \
                        event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE:

                    cid = msg.correlationIds()[0].value()
                    print("%s - %s" % (cid, msg))
                else:
                    print(msg)
            if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                eventCount += 1
                if eventCount >= options.maxEvents:
                    print("%d events processed, terminating." % eventCount)
                    break
            elif event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.TIMEOUT:
                for requestTemplate in snapshots:
                    session.sendRequestTemplate(
                        requestTemplate,
                        blpapi.CorrelationId(nextCorrelationId))
                    nextCorrelationId += 1
```

I don't know if endpoint and subscription management endpoint are 2 different things because I have one other code working properly and the endpoint is the IP of the server I am pulling the data.

Comment: The likely cause for this is connecting to a Desktop API instead of a BPIPE or Server API.
You're also missing the code that calls the snapshots; this is just the authorization section.

Comment: I added the snapshot request part and deleted the code for authorization since I am able to pass authorization successfully. 
Also, I figured out that endpoint is the ip address same as server ip. So I don't get how it can't find endpoint.
Is subscription management endpoint is totally something else?

Comment: Subscription Management Endpoint is your BPIPE.  Unless you're connecting to one, snapshots won't work.